# React Native - The right way to create bridge header in Xcode

Tags: ios, react-native, onesignal

I'm stuck on manually install [RN-onesignal on iOS](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup)

already followed the [instructions](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) but I got an error `RCTOneSignalExtensionService.h is not found`

after some research, I found [this issue](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/530#issuecomment-407500503) that tell me to manually create `bridge header`, but I don't know the right way to create a `bridge header` itself (because this is my first time using macOS)

I've tried this step :

1. in Xcode project go to `File->New->File`
2. choose Swift file and Targeting to `MyProject` and `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` then finish
3. add `#import "RCTOneSignalExtensionService.h"` in `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-Bridging-Header.h`
4. add `$(SRCROOT)/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-Bridging-Header.h` at `build setting OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension target`

but i got an error `Bridging header 'MyProjectPath/ios/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist`

> FYI : at this step `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-Bridging-Header.h` file is on my project folder

[image: Current Structure]

so i decided to drag n drop the `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-Bridging-Header.h` to `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` folder, but the error still persist

anyone can help me to fix the error?

BTW my Xcode version is **Version 8.3.2**

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, trying to solve this 3 hours.
Make sure you not missing this step: [image]

Comment: i'm confused on 3rd step given, should i add `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios` or `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios/RCTOneSignal`? but i've tried both of them but still no luck anyway

Comment: $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/ios